# Issue with mv command in a script

Tags: shell, scripting, quoting

This must be a very simple issue to solve, but I am stuck (not a UNIX pro). I need to move a gz to a target directory, but I get a `No such file or directory`.

```
NOW=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d-%T")

DEST="~/scripts/backup"
SQL_DUMP="db_dump_$NOW.sql.gz"
echo "$SQL_DUMP"

drush sql-dump | gzip -9 > $SQL_DUMP
mv -t $DEST $SQL_DUMP
```

The `sql.gz` is created properly, only the last command does not work. How should I use it? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is *not* with your `mv` command.

*Tilde expansion* is the name for what the shell does when it replaces the `~` character with the user's home directory, e.g. `/home/username`.  It is possible to tell the shell to not do this by quoting the tilde character.  This is exactly what you have done in

```
DEST="~/scripts/backup"
```

You have assigned to `DEST` the string `~/scripts/backup`.  This directory does not actually exist.  Two solutions:

- Don't quote the `~` character:

  ```
  DEST=~/scripts/backup
  ```
- Use `$HOME` instead:

  ```
  DEST="$HOME/scripts/backup"
  ```

#### A final debugging tip

Put `set -x` at the top of your script to turn on the `xtrace` option.  If you had done that you would have seen that the `mv` command was using the wrong directory, `~/scripts/backup` instead of `/home/yourname/scripts/backup`.

Answer (score -1):

Read **mv** manual

```
SYNOPSIS
    mv [SOURCE] [DEST]
```

And you may want to check if $DEST already exist:

```
if [ -d ${DEST} ]; then
    do something
fi
```

If not, use **mkdir** with **-p** as parameter to make parent directories.

```
...
else
    mkdir -p ${DEST}
fi
```

Comment: I did try those mv source target too, but same issue. I think it has to do with '~'. The directory exists, this is not the issue.

Comment: Then use absolute path: /home/user/scripts/backup, or use $HOME